# Supressing logging in an IPython notebook

Tags: python, logging, ipython

I use the built-in [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module to show progress messages while a function batch-processes frames of video. At `In[15]` in [this IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/raw.github.com/danielballan/mr/master/examples/mr%20simple%20example.ipynb), a usage guide I wrote, all the log messages are shown. Look for the large block of pink-highlighted text.

In a "live" notebook, open to editing, the messages are contained in a short scroll-able cell, which is fine. But here, displayed by IPython's notebook viewer, they are displayed in full. I'd to suppress them if I can, and without modifying the function that is generating the log messages. Is there a way?

Comment: IPython is no different than a console logger - thus, you can just set `propagate` to False, as shown in [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-i-disable-and-re-enable-console-logging-in-python)

Comment: IPython dev also have a %%capture magic that capture stderr to a variable. Do you have link to that mr package ?

Comment: That sounds useful. The link is https://github.com/danielballan/mr