# Fully disable python logging

Tags: python, logging

In my code I use `logging.info(...` and before that I configure with `logging.basicConfig(filename=...`. Is it possible to keep the logging lines in the code without them doing anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable logging on the standard error stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-disable-logging-on-the-standard-error-stream)

Answer (score 30):

You can use:

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

to [disable all logging calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.disable) which are at level CRITICAL or below. Effectively this disables all logging calls.

You can enable the logging for all loggers again (at their own logging levels) by doing:

```
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

Answer (score 11):

Logging has [the following structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html):

- *loggers* are arranged according to a namespace hierarchy with dot separators;
- each logger has a *level* (`logging.WARNING` by default for the root logger and `logging.NOTSET` by default for non-root loggers) and an *effective level* (the effective level of the parent logger for non-root loggers with a level `logging.NOTSET` and the level of the logger otherwise);
- each logger has a list of *filters*;
- each logger has a list of *handlers*;
- each handler has a *level* (`logging.NOTSET` by default);
- each handler has a list of *filters*.

Logging has [the following process](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) (represented by a flowchart):

[image: Logging flow.]

Therefore to disable a particular logger you can adopt one of the following strategies:

1. Set the level of the logger to `logging.CRITICAL + 1`.

   - Using the main API:

     ```py
     import logging

     logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
     logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL + 1)
     ```
   - Using the config API:

     ```py
     import logging.config

     logging.config.dictConfig({
         "version": 1,
         "loggers": {
             "foo": {
                 "level": logging.CRITICAL + 1
             }
         }
     })
     ```
2. Add a filter `lambda record: False` to the logger.

   - Using the main API:

     ```py
     import logging

     logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
     logger.addFilter(lambda record: False)
     ```
   - Using the config API:

     ```py
     import logging.config

     logging.config.dictConfig({
         "version": 1,
         "filters": {
             "all": {
                 "()": lambda: (lambda record: False)
             }
         },
         "loggers": {
             "foo": {
                 "filters": ["all"]
             }
         }
     })
     ```
3. Remove the existing handlers of the logger, [add a handler `logging.NullHandler()` to the logger](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) (to prevent events from being handled by the handler `logging.lastResort` which is a `logging.StreamHandler` using the current stream `sys.stderr` and a level `logging.WARNING`) and [set the attribute `propagate` of the logger to `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#loggers) (to prevent events from being handled by the handlers of the ancestor loggers of the logger).

   - Using the main API:

     ```py
     import logging

     logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
     for handler in logger.handlers.copy():
         try:
             logger.removeHandler(handler)
         except ValueError:  # in case another thread has already removed it
             pass
     logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
     logger.propagate = False
     ```
   - Using the config API:

     ```py
     import logging.config

     logging.config.dictConfig({
         "version": 1,
         "handlers": {
             "null": {
                 "class": "logging.NullHandler"
             }
         },
         "loggers": {
             "foo": {
                 "handlers": ["null"],
                 "propagate": False
             }
         }
     })
     ```

*Warning.* — Contrary to strategies 1 and 2 which only prevent events logged *by the logger* from being emitted by the handlers of the logger and its ancestor loggers, strategy 3 also prevents events logged *by the descendant loggers* of the logger (e.g. `logging.getLogger("foo.bar")`) to be emitted by the handlers of the logger and its ancestor loggers.

*Note.* — Setting the attribute `disabled` of the logger to `True` is not yet another strategy, as it is not part of the public API (cf. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80499):

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
logger.disabled = True  # DO NOT DO THIS
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `filter()` method has one small caveat. It doesn't propagate like handlers and levels do: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2014/02/python-logging-filters-do-not-propagate-like-handlers-and-levels-do/
So if you want to filter everything you need to walk through all handlers.

Comment: Note that adding a `NullHandler()` will only work if there's no existing handler. Otherwise it's completely futile.

Comment: _Levels_ and _handlers_ do not "propagate": logger's _effective level_ is inherited from parent loggers' level if not specified, and _log records_ propagate to handlers of parent loggers. But that is a good point: if you want to filter everything, you need to walk through, more precisely, all _child loggers_ (if you attach filters to loggers, like here) or all _parent handlers_ (if you attach filters to handlers, like in your blog example). I have updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: How about if I want to re-activate logging, once it has been disabled using the main api? I have a flask server and I want to activate / deactivate logging on a per request basis.

Comment: @LeeviL I would say just do the converse operation: if you enabled logging with the 1st solution, remove the `logging.NullHandler()` and set the `propagate` attribute to `True`; if you enabled logging with the 2nd solution, remove the `lambda record: False` filter.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: it seems that `disabled` is not supposed to be meant for public use. Look at [Maggyero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396144) for alternative solutions.**

Just disable the log handler and it won't write to anything anymore.

```
logging.getLogger().disabled = True
```

Do note that every logger can have handlers so there might be more.

Comment: Your 2nd solution disabling the logger is a good solution. However your 1st solution setting an empty list of handlers is wrong. Firstly because it is not thread safe (you should use the `removeHandler` method which uses a `threading.RLock()` instance to accomplish that). Secondly because the `logging.lastResort` handler will be used in the absence of handlers. Instead you should have added a `logging.NullHandler()` instance (to avoid the `logging.lastResort` handler) and set `propagate` to `False` to avoid log record propagation to parent loggers' handlers.

Comment: The `lastResort` handler didn't exist in Python 2 (it was added in 3.2) so when writing this 5 years ago I wasn't aware of it ;) https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort
As for thread safety, that's completely irrelevant here. Replacing a variable has no lock safety issues. I'll remove the first solution though, with the `lastResort` handler it's not a good solution anymore.

Comment: Even if the `lastResort` handler did not exist, the message ["No handlers could be found for logger X"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided) would be printed on `sys.stderr`, which is not what can be called "fully disabled logging".

Comment: That's (for Python 2) only the case when `raiseExceptions` is set which is not recommended on production systems. So the message would have been swallowed by the system.

Comment: Finally using the `disabled` attribute is not a good idea as it is actually not part of the public API (see [my discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue36318) with Vinay Sajip, the author of the `logging` library). So the correct solution is to either use a `lambda record: False` filter or a `logging.NullHandler()` handler without propagation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. It seems there's a `disable()` too: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.disable 
Now I'm wondering how that will behave.

Comment: Calling `logging.disable(level)` is like calling `logging.getLogger(logger).setLevel(level + 1)` on _all_ loggers. So if you want to disable logging for _all_ levels and for _all_ loggers, you can call `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)` or equivalently `logging.disable()`. But with this approach you cannot disable logging only for a specific logger. And if for some loggers you have defined a custom logging level higher than `logging.CRITICAL`—which is not recommended—, logging for these loggers will not be disabled (unless you specified that level in `logging.disable(level)`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want full disable logs first should in **logging.basicConfig()** set levevl equal **logging.NOTSET** because is zero level and then **logging.getLogger().disabled** set **True or False**.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Example for full disable:

```
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
     logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)

     logging.basicConfig(
     format="%(levelname) -10s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s  %(message)s",
     level=logging.NOTSET)

     logging.getLogger().disabled = True  # True, False

     logging.critical("Critical")
     logging.error("Error")
     logging.warning("Warning")
     logging.info("Info")
     logging.debug("Debug")
```