# Python custom logging handler tries to log itself during emit()

Tags: python, logging, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to implement a custom logging handler, which should post to a rabbitmq server<sup>1</sup>.

A basic setup of this would look something like this:

```
class RabbitMQHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int, queue: str,  level: int = 0) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.queue = queue

        super().__init__(level)


    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> None:
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            with pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port
            )) as connection:
                channel = connection.channel()
                channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue)
                channel.basic_publish(
                    exchange='',
                    routing_key=self.queue,
                    body=msg
                )
            self.flush()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
```

The issue here seems to be, that the `pika` module tries to log itself as soon as a connection is established, thus calling the `emit()` function recursively forever.

My question is whether should simply disable logging (how?) during the emit function, or if this is the wrong approach altogether?

**EDIT:** Putting the above handler into a separate logger would be one way to go, however I am wondering about a general solution to this question.

---

<sup>1</sup> I know there are [pip packages](https://pypi.org/project/python-logging-rabbitmq/) for this, but for this project I have to avoid dependencies as much as possible.

Comment: I see your edit. Any reason why you don't consider adding the handler to a separate logger to be general enough a solution?

Comment: @blhsing yes - actually I am quite sure your suggestion is the way to go - but what if the root logger is already used throughout the project and one does only want to add this additional handler to it? Again, I will most probably go with your suggestion anyway (feeling a bit dumb for not seeing it myself :D ) but I am curious :)

Comment: I see your point. Yeah in case you don't want to refactor your existing code too much you might want to simply [disable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647750/6890912) during `emit` indeed.

Comment: Note that disabling logging during `emit` is not thread-safe though, since one thread may disable logging during `emit` while another thread still has legitimate logging messages that are thrown away only because the shared root logger is disabled in the same time period.

Comment: gtk, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you added your custom logging handler to the root logger, and logging messages [propagate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to ancestor loggers by default, so messages logged by `pika` get propagated to the root logger and invokes your custom logging handler recursively.

The best practice in this case would be to add the custom logging handler to a non-root logger instance, and use that logger instead for the logging needs of your application.