# Logger prints to console even though FileHandler is defined

Tags: python

I am having some problem with the python logging module. In the following I create a "logger" which I will use later in my code. Here, I am using only the FileHandler but I see that when I log some message to this logger they also appear on the console.  Printing to console makes my whole program slow.

Following is the code:

```
  logger = logging.getLogger("Design")
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  #create a file handler which logs all INFO, DEBUG, ERROR messages

  fh = logging.FileHandler('Design.log', mode='w')

  fmt = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')       

  fh.setFormatter(fmt)

 #adding the handlers to logger
  logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `logger.handlers = []`

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Design")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.handlers = []

#create a file handler which logs all INFO, DEBUG, ERROR messages

fh = logging.FileHandler('Design.log', mode='w')

fmt = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')       

fh.setFormatter(fmt)

#adding the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

#### Edit

Add this option if you have previously set up `basicConfig()`

```
logger.propagate = False
```

Comment: I tried  setting "logger.handlers= []", but it still does the same.

Comment: Do I need to reset default basicConfig?

Comment: @boppu in that case take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2267567/1517864. Editted my answer accordingly

Comment: logger.propagate works. Thanks. I do have one more question, is there any way to print multiple lines to logger at once. I currently, print to a string and then I log the string at once to logger.

Answer (score 0):

What caused this error for me was the import statement.

### Working Statments

```
import logging
fh = logging.FileHandler('error.log', mode='w')
logger = getLogger(__name__)
```

### ERROR ON import *

```
from logging import *
fh = logging.FileHandler('error.log', mode='w')
logger = getLogger(__name__)
```

and did not change my code so I needed to be

```
from logging import *
fh = FileHandler('error.log', mode='w')
logger = getLogger(__name__)
```