# How to process logging event in Python only by handler?

Tags: python, logging, graylog

I define specific logger which I want to use only for sending messages to Graylog. How do I ban redirecting to console/file? I have other logger which writes to console/file:

```
import logging
import graypy

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
LOGGER0 = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER1 = logging.getLogger("graylog")

handler = graypy.GELFHandler(GRAYLOG_URL, GRAYLOG_PORT, debugging_fields = False)
LOGGER1.addHandler(handler)
LOGGER1.info("some message")
```

How do I prevent from printing "some message"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I disable and re-enable console logging in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-i-disable-and-re-enable-console-logging-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by setting:

```
LOGGER1.propagate = False
```