# How to disable the logging of Uvicorn?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, alembic, uvicorn

I am working on FastAPI - Uvicorn. I want to disable the logging by uvicorn. I need only the logs which are logged by the server.

[image: Log file]

I referred to this [blog](https://medium.com/1mgofficial/how-to-override-uvicorn-logger-in-fastapi-using-loguru-124133cdcd4e) and implemented the logging.

Comment: How did you make such color scheme for terminal/logging?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could change log level for getting only needed messages, there are a bunch of possible [options](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging):

```
uvicorn main:app --log-level critical
```

Answer (score 8):

I think I had the same issue.

To disable the logger one must first find the loggers, that shall be disabled. I did this by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module) stackoverflow post and [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1508) GitHub-Issue.

For me it works to disable just two loggers from uvicorn:

```
import logging
# ....CODE....
uvicorn_error = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error")
uvicorn_error.disabled = True
uvicorn_access = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access")
uvicorn_access.disabled = True
```

At first I tried the answer provided by @Sanchouz, but this didn't work out for me - Further setting `propagate = false` is by some regarded as a bad practice (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-disable-logging-on-the-standard-error-stream)) . As I wanted to do it programmatically I couldn't test the answer provided by @funnydman.

Hope this helps anyone, thinklex.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem definition

I had a similar problem and I found a solution. In my case, I created a small website with FastAPI to launch web scrappers in separate processes. I also created class-wrapper for loggers from `logging` module. My problem was: when I started my app inside Docker container with `uvicorn ...` command, which includes some settings for logging into file, all logging from any web scrapper would go into both scrapper's separate log file and server's log file. I have a lot of stuff to log, so it's quite a problem.

## Short answer

When you get your logger, just set it's `propagate` property to `False` like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
logger.propagate = False
```

## Long answer

At first I spent some time debugging insides of a `logging` module and I found a function called `callHandlers`, which loops through handlers of current logger and it's parents. I wrongly assumed, that root logger was responsible for that problem, but after some more testing it turned out, that actually root logger didn't have any handlers. It means, that some of uvicorn's logger was responsible for that, which makes sense, also considering [Thinklex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037954). I tried his solution too, but it doesn't fit me, because it disabled uvicorn's logging completely, and I don't want that, so I'll stick with preventing propagation on my loggers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if self.log_level is not None:
        if isinstance(self.log_level, str):
            log_level = LOG_LEVELS[self.log_level]
        else:
            log_level = self.log_level
        logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error").setLevel(log_level)
        logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").setLevel(log_level)
        logging.getLogger("uvicorn.asgi").setLevel(log_level)
    if self.access_log is False:
        logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").handlers = []
        logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").propagate = False
```

This is from uvicorn\config.py where config is done. See how they are disabling access logs if app is run with

> access_log=False

do the same thing for all three loggers they config

```
    # disable uvicorn logs
    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error").handlers = []
    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error").propagate = False

    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").handlers = []
    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").propagate = False

    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.asgi").handlers = []
    logging.getLogger("uvicorn.asgi").propagate = True
```