# Change the error stream in logger in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I dont want any logger prints in my terminal. I have separate log file where I will dump all the logger messages.

So now if I do

```
logger.exception('error')
```

The message will be shown in terminal which I dont want.

I assume I need to change something here in my code.

```
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

stream_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Edited:

I have seen the one answer here - [How to disable logging on the standard error stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-disable-logging-on-the-standard-error-stream)

According to that I need to set

```
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

If I do that in the logger file I am seeing some unnecessary prints.
So I want to be in

```
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

And not want any prints in the terminal.
So can somebody help ?

Comment: Are you using `logger.exception('error')` to log an exception?  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) `exception()` logs at the `error` level. Which is the level you've set your `stream_handler`

Comment: @MarceloPaco ```stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()``` This is how its initialized.  So by default If stream is not specified, sys.stderr is used.

Comment: Hmm... I found the answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-disable-logging-on-the-standard-error-stream> thanks @Ake.

Comment: so the answer is ```handler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)``` .